# Optimized insert in chuncks of millions of records, MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, performance, performance-testing, mysql5

I need to populate a MySQL table with random SHA-1 hash values, generated by PHP function. 
I`m trying to optimize the insert by splitting it in chunks of 10000.
My question is:
Is the following approach efficient? Here is the code.

```
//MySQL server connection routines are above this point
if ($select_db) {
$time_start = microtime(true);
//query
$query = 'INSERT INTO sha1_hash (sha1_hash) VALUES ';
for ($i=1; $i<1000001; $i++) {
 $query .= "('".sha1(genRandomString(8))."'),";
    $count++;
    if ($count ==10000) {
    //result
 $result = mysql_query(rtrim($query,',')) or die ('Query error:'.mysql_error());
    if ($result) mysql_free_result($result);
    $count = 0;
    }
}

$time_end = microtime(true);
echo '<br/>'. ($time_end - $time_start);
}

//function to generate random string
function genRandomString($length)
{
$charset='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
$count = strlen($charset);
 while ($length--) {
  $str .= $charset[mt_rand(0, $count-1)];
 }
return $str;
}
```

EDIT: The `$time_start` and `$time_end` variables are ONLY for performance testing purposes. Also the MySQL table has two fields only: `ID int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT` and `sha1_hash varchar(48) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL`, the engine is `MyISAM`
EDIT2: The computer hardware point of view is not related to the question.

Comment: Pay attention to max allowed packet size in your MySQL Admin settings: building very long queries (as those thousands of iterations suggest) might exceed that limit.

Comment: Efficient in what context?  total execution time? memory usage? system load?

Comment: Efficent in every mentioned way, Wally

Comment: Indeed, max allowed packet size was increased to 1024 Mb, nadirs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inserts are generally done in large batches because indexes are updated after each insert. Batching allows you to insert many records then update the indexes only once at the end instead of after each row.

However, in the case of an auto-incrementing primary key index, the index has to be extended in order to even add the new row, so you're not saving anything there since you don't have any other indexes.

Batching also saves on some overhead in the parsing of the queries and locking. However, you might also consider using parameterized queries (PDO).

Inserting one record at a time using PDO's parameterized query would also be very fast, since MySQL only has to parse the query once, and from then on, it uses a low overhead binary transfer of the row data.

You might lock the table before the insertion begins with `LOCK TABLES`. This will save a little bit in table lock overhead.

Also, since SHA1 will always be 40 character hex encoded ASCII value, you should consider using `CHAR(40)` instead of `VARCHAR()`. This will speed things up as well. Also, if the SHA1 column is indexed, use a single-byte character set instead of UTF8 to reduce the size of the index and speed things up.

Comment: Indeed, using char (40) instead of varchar (48) is a good point of improvement, especially when having millions of records. However, the length of input string may vary - it can be 8 or 20, or 32...put in short - the collisions are not so relevant (or plausible - collisions with a computational effort of fewer than 2 on power 80 operations)

Comment: It seems like plugging random values into a hash function could lead to collisions, but apparently you're right. If you found a collision in SHA1, you'd be famous.